# why does my app crash on button click to next page

Tags: android

why does my app crash when i click the button to go to the next page?

On the 1st page `onCreate` method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button startBtn = findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent ready = new Intent(view.getContext(), ready.class);
//          ready.putExtra(name, 1);
//          startActivityForResult(ready, 1);
            startActivity(ready);
        }
    });
}
```

On the 2nd page `onCreate` method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ready);
}
```

the app goes straight into a loop and then crashes.

log:

> at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4883)
>       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4851)
>       at com.example.ng_we.capsize.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
>       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6877)
>       at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26069)

it just says the error is at startActivity();

code for button xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/startBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

this is the code for ready.xml, its simple... i dont think its the cause

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_marginTop="250px"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startName"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:layout_marginTop="250px"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:text="ARE YOU READY?"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="100px"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/readyBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ready"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is a crash log?

Comment: please show button xml code

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.ready); this layout is ready xml file?

Comment: Yes its the ready xml.

Comment: @WeiXiong Add full crash log.? Did you declared activity in manifest file.?

Comment: @Mohamed Mohaideen AH thanks, it worked haha, my bad been a long time since i touched android... forgot some stuff hahaha

Comment: @WeiXiong Welcome glad to help happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add in the 2nd page to the manifest file...

Answer (score -1):

```
this is my Button code :
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/startBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

//-------------------------this is click listener of button-------------
    Button startBtn = findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent ready = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ready.class);
                startActivity(ready);
            }
        });
```

Comment: tried to change the getContext() to MainActivity.this, still same problem

Comment: button listener is perfect .. problem on xml file